# Customized menu bar in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menubar

I'm using visual studio 2008 and i'm building application in vb.net, i want to design an attractive menu bar for my application. Something like shown in the image. Please guide me[image]

Comment: WinForms? What has been tried?

Comment: @Lomed : Ya its windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many 3rd party controls that you can download or buy to create professional looking menu bars and stuff. But Visual Studio already comes bundled with the toolstrip control. For the time being, get familiar with the toolstrip control to create menu items.

Check this out. This should get you started :)

http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/toolstrip-control-in-vb.net

Comment: Thats great, And what if i want to increase height of my menu bar, currently its fixed to 24 pixel. And also i want to add text below menu icon, please guide me.

Comment: You can download .png icons from iconarchive.com. Set the toolstrip's ImageScaling property to the size of your icon. If you're icon is 48x48, then set ImageScaling property to 48,48. If you added say a button. Right click the button and click on DisplayStyle, choose Image and Text to display both image and text. That's it.

Comment: If it answered your question, please do mark my post as answered ;) thanks